# How to Get Session ID when using the Nancy Razor setup for .Net?

Tags: asp.net, razor, nancy

I need to add the SessionID to a global tracking script in the layout, however apparently there isn't direct access to the HttpContext from the view with Nancy so I cant do something like:

```
@HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID.ToString()
```

I inherited this app from someone else and just haven't used Nancy much at all and could use some help.

Answer (score 0):

In Nancy there is no such thing as the session ID - by default, Nancy sessions are simply a dictionary which is encrypted and stored in a cookie, so the session itself is presented by the client in full rather than stored server side and associated with a client by use of an ID.

What you need to do is set your own cookie with a unique identifier and use that as your "session" ID.  Or you can add a unique identifier to the session itself, but be aware that cookies have a limited size, and browsers tend to truncate cookies that are too large (resulting in an empty session dictionary), so put stuff like this into its own cookie wherever possible.